# Asynchronous NSURLConnection getting failed with auto mistypecasting of class instance

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am creating a single instance of a chase class which has a dictionary as a property.
As I add elements to dictionary, I can see the change in the count of dictionary keys.
But when I am accessing, it's firing a crash with message like given below:

> [__NSCFString connection:didReceiveData:];
>
> [__NSCFArray reqmap]; etc..

Basically, I am mapping request url with `NSData` instance, so that the response could be mapped and appended properly, asynchronously.

Code:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.cacheDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
        self.reqmap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (CommunityImageCache*)getSharedCommunityImageCache
{
    if (sharedCommunityImageCacheInstance == nil) {
        sharedCommunityImageCacheInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedCommunityImageCacheInstance;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString* keyurl = [[[connection currentRequest] URL] absoluteString];
 //crash point >>>>
    NSMutableData* tempdata = (NSMutableData*)[self.reqmap objectForKey:keyurl];
    [tempdata appendData:data];
    
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection 
{
    NSString* keyurl = [[[theConnection currentRequest] URL] absoluteString];
    NSMutableData* tempdata = [self.reqmap objectForKey:keyurl];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:tempdata];  
    [self.cacheDict setObject:img forKey:[@"image:\\\\public\\" stringByAppendingString:keyurl]];
    [self.reqmap removeObjectForKey:keyurl];
}


-(UIImage *)getImageFromUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    UIImage* image = nil;
    
        image = [self.cacheDict objectForKey:url];
        if (!image) 
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfile.png"];
            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            
            NSString* localUrl = [NSString stringWithString:url];
            NSString* finurl = [localUrl substringFromIndex:[@"image:\\\\public\\" length]]; 
            UIImage* img = nil;
            NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finurl]
                                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                 timeoutInterval:60.0];
            
            NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            NSURLConnection* connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
            NSString* keyurl = [[[connect currentRequest] URL] absoluteString];
            [self.reqmap setObject:data forKey:keyurl];
}
}
```

Needed badly, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];` -- Why not simply `[[self alloc] init];`???

Comment: what *is* keyurl when the crash happens?  if you put a "`NSLog`" there, do you get a value?

Comment: The keyurl is there, but when it comes to connection call back funtion, the dataType of dictionary is auto represented as NSString or NSArray, where its getting crashed.

Comment: well, I think `[self alloc] init]` would do, but anyway we need to call `super alloc` in `[self init]`. right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, reqmap is suppose to contain NSMutableData objects, right ?
They need instantiation, something like :
[self.reqmap setValue:[[NSMutableData alloc] init] forKey:@"TheKey"];

Comment: Hey, I apologize for late reply. Thanks nate!, for corrections. Hey @bob, I have done the same, but getting crashed for the same.

Comment: Hey! sorry for late reply. I have done the same in fact. 'reqmap' is NSMutableDictionary and value that I am setting is NSMutableData for the given NSUrl key.

Answer (score 0):

You should also implement

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

when you're using NSURLConnection.  I don't see it in your code above.  Then you should alloc/reset the data in this function.

What is the actual error you are seeing?  It sounds like either reqmap isn't an NSDictionary (though it is in your code above), or the object you're retrieving isn't a NSMutableData.

In total, implement:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: No, I have implemented above said functions. And reqmap is a NSDictionary and and objects that I am retrieving are NSMutableData type. Thanks.